# Life Cycle of Qt Forms (or Windows)

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml, desktop

How can I control life cycle of QML forms (I mean windows)? I am talking about onCreate, onResume, onPause etc. methods on Android or life cycle of views on iOS. And Can I work this life cycle of QML forms on Android, iOS, Windows 10 Mobile, desktop etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design of Qt Quick (QML) applications is different from Android ones. There is no difference between views and objects like `Button`, `Text`, etc. Every QML object with graphical representation inherits `Item` and it is possible to define `Component.onCompleted` and `Component.onDestruction` functions. They will be executed once object is created and destroyed. If you also need a *pause* signal I suggest creating functions `pause()` and `resume()` in every view you create and create an object that will manage the views - create, destroy, pause and resume them.
Please notice that you need to take care of transitions between views and states yourself. Also as you can create your own QML objects it is worth considering creating a template of a view and then only inherit it.

This will work with every system you deploy the app on.

If you have more questions, need example etc. consider editing the question or leaving a comment.

---

I want to thank [BaCaRoZzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538363/bacarozzo) once again for useful tips. I added them to this answer.

---

I have created an example project that tries to mimic Android app life cycle. This will work with every OS. This is just an example but I think that similar approach may be used in release source. However, first you need to understand the nature of the QML. This is high level language that is already being managed by some other process. It is far different from Java. For example take a look at the fragment of the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) about a state used by background processes:

> A Qt Quick application should not usually handle this state at the QML
>   level. Instead, you should unload the entire UI and reload the QML
>   files whenever the application becomes active again.

So if I were you I would only save sensitive data when I detect application is going to background. No need to try and unlod views etc. It would be needless uphill struggle becuase QML is not designed for this. Instead let your app be killed if OS needs more memory.

You can find the example project [here](https://github.com/fhazubski/Android-app-life-cycle-in-Qt-Quick). You can use it if you want. It contains comments to let you better understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example for create, destroy, onstart, onresume, onpause etc. for all platforms?

Comment: @İbrahim Yes. I will update my answer in a couple of hours :)

Comment: There is also the `Qt` object and its [`application`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) property. it is supposed to work in a consistent way among platforms.

Comment: @FilipHazubski Thank you. You solved my problem your project.